# How can I edit the final HTML structure of the whole web page

Tags: php, shortcode, html

I am creating an online shop web page and I am using the "Almaira Shop" theme.

This theme lets me put a page template that haves a lot of customizable sections that I can edit with the "customize" tool. One of its sections is called Product Filter. It is basically a preview of the shop that shows the categories. It looks like this:

[image: It looks like this]
The thing is that I want to change the order of the "Clothing, Other, Sneakers", which is by default on alphabetic order. I cannot change it with the customize tool, so I looked for the file, to edit it, but when I go into the file, it says this code

```
<?php
if( shortcode_exists( 'almaira-shop' ) ){
do_shortcode("[almaira-shop section='almaira_shop_show_frontpage']");
}
?>
```

I'm guessing that it is a shortcode from some file, but I can't find it. I did the thing when you press F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I, and the HTML code of the webpage appears like this:

[image]

And I managed to change it (Just changing the "Sneakers"  at the top of the section, so it would appear first), but when you refresh the web page, the changes disappear because you are only changing it locally. So I was wondering if there would be a way to edit the final HTML structure of the web page so I can change the order with just putting the  at the top. :)

Comment: Your best bet is going to be to contact the developer of the Almaira Shop Theme.  The shortcode that gets generated is controlled by the theme itself so what you'd need to do is actually edit or augment that chunk of code and that would then mean you either can't update from that point forward or if you do update, your code will get overwritten and you'll have to start over.  Are you by any chance using a Child Theme to give yourself more flexibility?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using a child theme, do I have to create it or something? I will get in contact with the developers, thanks again

Comment: Just be aware that this is generally not how WordPress or any of these plugins work. They don't produce HTML that could can edit arbitrarily. However plugins _might_ let you replace parts of the templates that they use. The exact methods allowed will depend on the theme or plugin in question.

Comment: Ok thank you :)

Comment: When you changed it in the inspector it does not change it on your server.

Answer (score 0):

This theme has a companion plugin called **hunk-companion**.

I ssh'd to my server and did `grep -iRl "almaira_shop_show_frontpage"` inside the `wp-content` folder and it returned this:

`plugins/hunk-companion/almaira-shop/almaira-shop-admin/almaira_shop_shortcode.php`

I found that in plugins/hunk-companion/almaira-shop/almaira-shop-frontpage you have all the sections' .php files.

You can now copy the code you need into your own [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) file to create your custom frontpage in your [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) (that's what I'm about to do!).

Good Luck!